# How to change CSS attribute based on number of elements which can be found only after loading the stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

When there are two divs i need a margin-left space before 1st div. But when there are 3 divs there should be no margin-left space.

The number of divs will be a dynamic content based on data from server side.So there can be 2 or 3 divs dynamically.

Required:

Space Div1 Div2

Div1  Div2 Div3

How can this be achieved in a simple CSS?

Comment: Can you paste some of the code you're working on?

Comment: I've added an extension to my answer below, adding functionality for any amount of elements, using only margin to push the element in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing with the container and the flex instead of margins

```css
.caja{
width:100%;
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.caja span{
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <span>span1</span>
  <span>span2</span>
</div>

<div class="caja">
  <span>span1</span>
  <span>span2</span>
  <span>span3</span>
</div>
```

The other option is javascript, you could make a count of the elements and if there is more than 2, add the margin you need or deleting it in your case:

```js
$(".caja").each(function(){
  var caja = $(this).find("span").length;
  if(caja>2){
    $(this).find('span').css('margin','0');
  }
});
```

```css
.caja span{
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caja">
<span>span 1</span>
<span>span 2</span>
</div>

<div class="caja">
<span>span 1</span>
<span>span 2</span>
<span>span 3</span>
</div>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: @dom_ahdigital, why should the JS solution be accepted? OP specifically asked for a CSS only solution, for which there are several.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** see example at bottom for a solution that's compatible with any amount of elements within the container, that centers them using only `float` and `margin`.

It's quite possible using css only utilizing `nth-last-of-type()` and `nth-of-type()` - at least if the max number of elements is 3 (might be able to tweak css for more). Check example below.

Explanation: `nth-last-of-type(2)` targets the first element if there are only 2 elements, but targets the 2nd if there are 3 elements. `nth-of-type(n + 2)` targets all the elements from the 2nd and forth and cancels the style from previous if there are more than 2 elements. The `n +` isn't necessary in this example, but included in case more elements could appear.

```
<div class="container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.container div{
float:left;
width:30%;
height:50px;
background:red;
border:1px solid;
}
.container div:nth-last-of-type(2){
margin-left:16%;
background:blue;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(n + 2){
margin:0;
background:green;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ufzwkzvu/5/

Note that the colors are just applied to distinguish the elements from each other.

---

**Edit:** example working for any number of elements within the container.

```css
.floater {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The relevant css is inbetween comment below and the next */
/* Relevant css start */

.floater:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 16.66%;
  background: blue;
}

.floater:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 33.33%;
  background: blue;
}

.floater:nth-of-type(3n - 1) {
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
}

.floater:nth-of-type(3n) {
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
}

/* Relevant css end */

span.clearfix {
  clear: left;
  display:block;
}
.spacer{
  padding:20px 0;
}
.container{
  padding:20px 0;
  clear:both;
}
.container:nth-of-type(2n){
  background:#e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer">1 element</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>

<div class="spacer">2 elements</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>

<div class="spacer">3 elements</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>

<div class="spacer">4 elements</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>

<div class="spacer">5 elements</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>

<div class="spacer">9 elements</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>

<div class="spacer">10 elements</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>

<div class="spacer">11 elements</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @superuser33333, maybe something should be clarified. Do you want there to always be 3 columns, even if there isn't enough content to fill them all? Or did you want to center your content if you have less than 3 columns? If you want content to center itself, then this is definitely the correct answer. Otherwise, I think I'm the only one to provide an answer that holds three column layout, even if there are only two columns worth of content. Which is the correct interpretation?

Answer (score -1):

You may consider [css-grid](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/):

Whatever is wrapping these divs (whether another div or the body) will need the style either `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "a b c";
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
}
```

```html
<h4>Two div</h4>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="b">Two</div>
  <div class="c">Three</div>
</div>

<h4>Three div</h4>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">One</div>
  <div class="b">Two</div>
  <div class="c">Three</div>
</div>
```

Just to explain a bit more:

The `display: grid` of course, sets us up to allow our children to be arranged into a grid.

`grid-template-columns:` determines how many/what sizes our columns on the grid will be. The `1fr` is a unit of measure like `100px` or `33%`, but unlike `px` or `%`, `fr` dynamically allocates a fraction of the whole. (so `1fr 1fr 1fr` allocates 3 equally sized columns, we could have also done things like `1fr 2fr` which would allocate the first column as 1/3 the total width and the second as 2/3 the total width)

`grid-template-areas:` gives us a fantastic organizational strategy. We can name our grid locations to make them easier to assign what content goes where. We've named our columns `a` `b` and `c`.

`grid-area` is just how we reference where in the grid we want to be rendered by the name we set in `grid-template-areas`.

---

Another option is to use float right to your advantage

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.box{
  float: right;
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Two</div>
  <div class="box">One</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Three</div>
  <div class="box">Two</div>
  <div class="box">One</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mind explaining what is wrong with my answer? I've show two css-only methods for accomplishing what the OP asked for?